# Resources for learning about creating an obscure 'public' URL in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 4.2 and Devise for access control. I would like to create a 'public' view of a index.html.erb page, which would be visible to anybody with the link. So it would be an obscure URL, that the user could share with others.

I have troubles approaching this problem. Any ideas for resources that I could study?

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what you mean by "obscure" in this instance?

Comment: Similar to e.g. on Youtube, where you can have an "unlisted" item, with a URL that you can share with others, but it's not found by the bots.

Comment: Do you just mean bots, or spiders?  Bots will respect the rules in `robots.txt` so you can use that with a generic path for items you don't want to get search indexed.

Comment: I guess my problem is how to toggle between the public and private states.   Perhaps I could make a route for another path, which wouldn't have access control enabled, and there the public content would appear from the user's private index.html.erb?

Answer (score 0):

One of possible ways related to use [MessageEncryptor](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/MessageEncryptor) to encrypt information about users allowed to view your page (i.e. encrypt them `id`s) and pass it as URL parameter. Then just decrypt this parameter in your `index` action and check that current user in the list of allowed users.

I think you get common idea. So, just adopt it for your case.

Comment: The question doesn't state that the users it is being shared with are Registered users of the site.

Comment: That's true, users don't need to be registered. Users should be able to share the URL with anybody.